# How to implement a OnItemSelectedListener for Spinner in Dialog Box

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner, android-dialog, onitemclicklistener

I have a Dialog Box in my `MainActivity` that is activated by touching a cog button in my Layout. When it appears, it contains a drop down `Spinner`. The `Spinner` works and produces a scrollable list of items, so that is good at least.

Albeit, I am stuck on correctly applying an `OnSpinnerItemSelectedListener` that works, which I want to customise in order to provide responses for each item selected.

Is anybody able to help me by providing advice on how best to apply a Listener and get it to work please? Your help would be massively appreciated!

With the code below, I have only included the portion of my `MainActivity` that references the Dialog Box and Spinner inside of that box. If you require further code, then please let me know - I'm more than happy to provide more info! `PowerSpinnerView` references the type of `Spinner` I'm using (from a third party dependency implemented in my Gradle file).

```
options = findViewById(R.id.optionscog);

options.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    private PowerSpinnerView spItems;

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_options_menu);

        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());

        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

        View back = dialog.findViewById(R.id.arrow);

        PowerSpinnerView powerSpinnerView = (PowerSpinnerView) 
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.spItems);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        back.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        Bitmap map = takeScreenShot(MainActivity.this);

        Bitmap fast = fastblur(map, 50);

        final Drawable draw=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),fast);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(draw);

        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

        dialog.show();

    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `PowerSpinnerView` from a 3rd party, so I looked at its [documentation](https://github.com/skydoves/PowerSpinner#onspinneritemselectedlistener) for the `click listener`:

```
powerSpinnerView.setOnSpinnerItemSelectedListener(new OnSpinnerItemSelectedListener<String>() {
 @Override public void onItemSelected(int oldIndex, @Nullable String oldItem, int newIndex, String newItem) {
   // do whatever you need here 
 }
});
```

the item you select is `newItem` and its index is `new index`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Avital! I've applied this to my code and can confirm that it works well. I have since entered a few responses to item selections and this too seems to work well. Thanks again and all the best. I have marked your answer as the chosen one and upvoted it too.

Comment: so glad to hear! have fun coding :)

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, but one last question if ok? Do you know how I could save the Spinner selection and then re-load the same selection when the App is next loaded? I've seen something called Shared Preferences being used, but couldn't fully wrap my head around it all. Thanks!

Comment: np. I added another answer for your new question

Answer (score 1):

For saving the spinner selection, all that you need is adding an attribute at the XML file:

```
app:spinner_preference_name="spinner_chs"
```

all the saving work is done by the [3rd party library](https://github.com/skydoves/PowerSpinner#store-and-restore-a-selected-position)

Comment: Hello again. Apologies, further daft question (and hopefully the very last!), but I was wondering how I would reference this in the OnCreate method when the app starts up again? It saves the last selected choice in the Spinner inside of the dialog box when I open the dialog box up again, but does not apply the action related to the last known selection of the Spinner when the app is opened up. Hopefully that makes sense! Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - do you have 2 spinners? in the dialog box and in the app? or only one in the dialog box?

Comment: Hello. Apologies. I meant just the 1 spinner in the dialog box. The spinner selection saves every time I re-open the app, but doesn't apply the action related to the selection. I.e. I select 'EUR currency' from the Spinner and on my MainActivity the currency is now Euros. I exit the app and re-open it, but the currency is as it was before (not Euros), even though the Spinner still says it is.

Comment: of course. the spinner "remembers" the value in it, but the app doesn't know what it is... I'd use dahredprefferences for that. very very simple. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences